# ORDER BY specific field in Nested JSON list

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

How to order by field 'created_at' inside list. Sample JSON attached below.

```
create table the_table (id int, value jsonb);
insert into the_table
values 
(1, 
'{
  "created_on": 123,
  "approvals": [
    {
      "id": "446",
      "isPending": true,
      "isReadyToApprove": true,
      "created_at": 124
    },
    {
      "id": "191",
      "isPending": true,
      "isReadyToApprove": true,
      "created_at": 124
    }
  ]
}'), 
(2, 
'{
  "created_on": 456,
  "approvals": [
    {
      "id": "447",
      "isPending": true,
      "isReadyToApprove": true,
      "created_at": 125
    },
    {
      "id": "192",
      "isPending": true,
      "isReadyToApprove": true,
      "created_at": 125
    }
  ]
}'), 
(3, 
'{
  "created_on": 789,
  "approvals": [
    {
      "id": "448",
      "isPending": true,
      "isReadyToApprove": true,
      "created_at": 126
    },
    {
      "id": "193",
      "isPending": true,
      "isReadyToApprove": true,
      "created_at": 126
    }
  ]
}');
```

Comment: You have multiple values for `created_at` in each row. Which one should be used for sorting? Also a value of `124` for an attribute named `created_at` seems strange to me.

Comment: created_at is timestamp. so it will be something like this numeric value. created_at field has multiple values but I need to order by any one.

Comment: A timestamp [isn't a number](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/). This really looks like an abuse of JSON, this could easily be stored in a properly normalized one-to-many relationship with a `timestamp` (or timestamp with time zone`) column, then sorting will be lot easier.

Comment: Unix timestamp looks like this numeric value. In any case, I need help with sorting based on this ''created_at'' field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care which of the many created_at you are sorting by (which sounds a bit strange), then just pick the first one:

```
select *
from the_table
order by (value -> 'approvals' -> 0 ->> 'created_at')::int
```

Comment: This works. Can you please help me with if I don't want to give any index.

Comment: You stated: "*but I need to order by any one*" so the first one is as good any.

Comment: Yes, it is. Just wanted to know if there's any possibility if I don't give any index then how it can be done.